# Running VSQL Query in Crontab, Bash on Windows

Tags: bash, cron, vsql

I am trying to test a very simple VSQL query crontab job within my Bash environment in Windows 10 to automate some of the Vertica pulls I do for work on a regular basis. I made sure to set up VSQL correctly for the Bash environment specifically by downloading and extracting the relevant Vertica client into `/opt/vertica/bin` and then added this to `PATH=` in `~/.profile`. Using the command `vsql` in Bash works.

I want to run the following executable script in crontab:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

vsql -dxxxxxxx -hxxxxxxxxxxx-Uxxxxxxx -wxxxxxxxxxxxx -f /mnt/c/Users/Even.Chandler/Documents/code/sql/script.sql -o /mnt/c/Users/Even.Chandler/Desktop/test.txt
```

From reading some previous questions on similar topics, I know I need to specifically call out the environment to be used for this pull, but this is where I am unsure. I tried including `export PATH="/opt/vertica/bin"` in the script file, but that still doesn't run the crontab job. Do I need to reference `./profile` in some way? I have tested the bash script on its own as well as running a separate simple crontab job to make sure that stuff is set up correctly and both work. Here is the crontab job I am trying to run:

```
0 10 * * 1 /mnt/c/Users/Even.Chandler/Desktop/vsql_crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I should have simply written `/opt/vertica/bin/vsql` right in the script instead of using `export PATH=`.